# Unexpected results when echoing the $value of a foreach loop

Tags: php

I've written the following code:

```
$hierachy = new hierachy;
$iterator = $hierachy->singlePathroot($name1);

try {
    print_r($iterator);

    foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
        echo $value;
        echo $value['0'];
    }
}
```

The result of the `print_r` is…

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Fruit ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Red ) )
```

…but below that, the echo statements produce `ArrayArray`.

How can I echo the same values I see in the `print_r` output?

Comment: Why is your indentation so bad?

Comment: Try use foreach($iterator as $key => &$value) !Notice &-character.

Comment: Now it is echoing ok, but the query statement below  will display all the node parent until it finds the root, I am only looking to display one level above in other words the next parent . "SELECT parent.name 
FROM categories AS node,
categories AS parent
WHERE node.left_node BETWEEN parent.left_node AND parent.right_node
AND node.name = '{$node_name}'
ORDER BY parent.right_node AND node.left_node"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo like this:

```
echo $iterator [0]['name'];
echo $iterator [1]['name'];
```

And in your loop:

```
$hierachy = new hierachy;
$iterator = $hierachy->singlePathroot($name1);
try {
   print_r($iterator);
   foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
   {
       echo $value['name'];
   }
} catch (Exception $e) { }
```

Comment: it is incredible man I have tried everything and it either come empty o just echo $value['name'];. echo $value['name']; will indeed echo but both names Fruit and Red and if I do echo $value[0]['name']; or echo $value[1]['name']; to echo value name in the first iteration there will be nothing in the screen. blank.

Comment: i realized that the $iterator was indeed the array so what I needed to echo was the $iterator instead of fiting it into the foreach loop and echo it through the $value

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
echo $value['name'];
```

Comment: Need to say I just need the name of the array[0], so that would be echo $value['name'][0]; hope that works thanks you for your answer

Comment: @fello: just copy paste this in your foreach loop instead of `echo $value`

Comment: I just looking to print the iteration [0] of [0] and [1], but it is incredible man I have tried everything and it either come empty o just echo $value['name'];. echo $value['name']; will indeed echo but both names Fruit and Red and if I do echo $value[0]['name']; or echo $value[1]['name']; to echo value name in the first iteration there will be nothing in the screen. blank.

Comment: I added the append didn't bring about the value from $iterator instead Jon comment made me realized it was the $iterator variable holding the values no the $value. Even though that with the append it should pass from $iterator to $value but didn't happen. any ways This query is targeting the parent or root as all the parents of the nested table and I only want a depth above to be interpreted as aparent not the root.

Comment: Query 

    `SELECT parent.name 
    FROM categories AS node,
    categories AS parent
    WHERE node.left_node BETWEEN parent.left_node AND parent.right_node
    AND node.name = '{$node_name}'
    ORDER BY parent.right_node AND node.left_node"`

i AM LOOKING the parent.name of the next level above not the root of the whole tree as the parent so it means the query will have to have a depth like function to only take the next level above.